# Store PDF in MySQL database

Tags: php, pdf, symfony, twig

I am developing an application and I need to create invoices in PDF. I'm using [pdfbundle](https://github.com/psliwa/PdfBundle) and PDF files are created correctly:

```
public function helloAction()
{
    $format = $this->get('request')->get('_format');
    $name = "work!!!";
    return $this->render(sprintf('miomioBundle:Venta:helloAction.%s.twig', $format), array('name' => $name));
}
```

But how could I store that file in the database?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'd be far better off storing them on disk as files and reference their location in your DB. So store:

> /path/to/store/invoice_434992.pdf

in a relevant table, each with a unique filename and reference it where you need to.

Answer (score 3):

Is there any particular requirement you want to store those pdfs in the database. Generally its a bad idea to store large binary content in the database.

Let the invoices be in files, with a unique filename, and store the just the path to file in the database table.

Comment: sorry I meant to save the pdf on the server. I first want to prove that the PDF is saved on the server and then I'll put the path in mysql. someone help me to save the pdf on the server? thanks

Answer (score 2):

I've done this. There is avery good article on how to do it.

http://www.php-mysql-tutorial.com/wikis/mysql-tutorials/uploading-files-to-mysql-database.aspx

As others have said, it may not be a good idea to store binary data in a database.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a table in your database that is:

```
____________________________________________
| ID | TIME | QUERY | PDF_NAME | PDF_FILE  |
|----|------|-------|----------|-----------|
...
```

The type of the PDF_FILE would be BLOB, and the rest are self-explanatory. This way, if you wanted, you could search for the result of a query that happened a while back.